# Use an interface defined class's other methods and keep intellisense

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, interface

The question is about the following:

```
IUser user = new Guest();
var stuff = user.guestname; //no definition for guestname
```

Here I get an error that `IUser` contains no guestname (of course).
I need a method or property that gives me what I want - to get the instantiated class's members even if it was defined as an interface.

I actually do have that, using dynamics:

`IUser` shall define an `Instance` prop like so:

```
dynamic Instance { get; }
```

and implemented by `Guest`:

```
public dynamic Instance
{
    get
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Piece of cake, I can get the instantiated type now and it works.

```
IUser user = new Guest();
var stuff = user.Instance.guestname; //runs fine.
```

**BUT THE ISSUE**

...is of course that I have no intellisense because of the dynamic type.

I thought of:

- defining an Invoke inside the interface and implement a `getter` in all the classes that implement this interface, and return their own value, but the interface doesn't know the classes that will implement it so it can return only that `IUser`, so useless
- trying this with generics, but then I have to call it like so:

  `user.Get<Admin>().SomeMethod()`;
  so it is basically not more than using `(user as Admin)`, so no help.
- What I'm thinking about now is that I should create the getter methods dynamically, say at the initialization of the program, to look for all the classes that implement this `IUser` and add the appropriate getter inside. I have no clue if it is doable or if so, then how to do it.

**SO THE QUESTION AGAIN**

Is that how to achieve what I did with the `dynamic` keyword, but actually **keeping** Visual Studio's intellisense feature?

Comment: so you are trying to use OOP features and at the same time you are using dynamics which is exactly against OOP!

Comment: it doesn't matter as long as it works :D

Comment: So you want to write bad code?

Comment: I'm more prone to error when I lose intellisense or when I constantly check that if the IUser is my given class and if so, use it as that.

Comment: it DOES matter. you are doing it really wrong way. you either use static or dynamic types. these are completely opposite. Why not just cast `IUser` to `Guest` and use its methods.

Comment: What you are doing here is what we call a "code smell" and violates the SOLID principles. If you have an object of type `IUser` then you should always treat it as such. If you find you need to break out to use other properties then you should reconsider your overall structure.

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question as it is not directly tied to it, but I won't know which class will I get into that IUser, but will have to use all its features when I get it. It can be an Admin, a Guest, a Customer etc and they do stuff differently.

Comment: Then define a property or method on the interface that each of the child objects can implement

Comment: Then you have a BIG design issue. You either need to use *specific* object properties (so you just cast it to whatever type you need) OR you need to use *common* properties (then just add those to your `IUser` interface)

Comment: It seems like so. The reason for this that The system can have only 1 user logged in and depending on who that is, can we use certain functionalities. We kept a variable for the user currently logged in and this is how this turned out.

Comment: Why are you upcasting it to IUser in the first place?

Comment: IUser is implemented by all the users (of course) and the system works depending on who uses it. I don't know which kind of user will log in, but once they are using it, they need their - and only their - capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various methods, the simplest is to cast the object to the type you need, for example:

```
IUser user = new Guest();

...

var guest = user as Guest;
var guestName = guest.guestname;
```

However, this is almost always a code smell. What you really should be doing is to define the properties and methods on the interface and let the child object implement them. For example:

```
public interface IUser
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Guest : IUser
{
    private readonly string _guestName;

    public Guest(string guestName)
    {
        _guestName = guestName;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _guestName;
    }
}

public class Admin : IUser
{
    private readonly string _adminName;

    public Guest(string adminName)
    {
        _adminName = adminName;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return _adminName;
    }
}
```

Comment: so basically design again is more viable. Thanks for pointing out the errors!